# Advanced Image editor Tool PHP

Tags: image, windows-vista, editing

I want the tool to develop like http://vistaprint.in/. It has advanced image editor tool.

So i want to create the same in PHP. Do you have any references for creating the same in PHP.

Do you have any references in javascript or PHP ?

Comment: Have you tried searching for something in google?

Comment: I have tried, But could not get it anything specific. Online software are there but they are not useful for me. If you have anything then let me know.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1):

Use the SVG editor for this kind of feature. Reference is https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Link only answers might not be much helpful. A little more explanation might help out fellow programmers how it works. As the link might not exist in future.